remove 1 second pulses from digital signal that has 5 second pulses
Edit: Hooray i got it to work now: 
I needed to remove the rogue 1 second pulses from signal that has longer 5 second width pulses.
Since Timer A might not be fast enough i might have needed to buffer/delay the signal.
Expired Q: Any recommendations for a buffer?
Edit: i forgot to mention, there is an unexpected burst/pulse of less than 1 sec which is coming out of nowhere.
For now i am trying 

This looks an XY-problem: What would be the advantage of disconnecting the panel from the charger?

My solar charger is charging my 24V battery at 29Volts , but my inverter can only handle 28Volts.

(Please don't comment comments asking for clarification or complementary information: edit your post.) Explore LDO controllers (linear voltage regulation using external MOSFETs).

(If you knew beforehand when you were going to need max discharge capacity, limiting float voltage to 28 V (below 7*4.15 V(?)) at all other times would benefit battery life expectancy. Care to include (a hyperlink to) the charger specs?)

Solar charger is Solarix PRS3030 charging my 24V battery to 30V. LeadAcid Battery says Cycle Use 28V to 29.4V

It isn't clear what the problem to be solved is. The question body mentions filtering out pulses of 1 second duration, yet a comment mentions the solar charger outputting a higher voltage than an inverter can handle.

Bullet point from the(?) product page: "Inverters must not be connected to the load output." - hope it's OK to connect them to the battery.

With CMOS AND gate:
The diode helps to quickly discharge the capacitor when Input is Low to circuit be ready for next pulse.


Busy soldering..  is that a 22 picofarads (pF) capacitor?

It is a 22uF (microfarad) capacitor. Together with 47k resistor in series makes charging time constant Tau=RC=47k22u=1.034sec

But "tau" isn't the switching time of this circuit. CMOS gates typically switch at Vcc/2, so you need a factor of 0.693 in there -- which means a larger tau of 1.44 seconds.

it unfortunately is not working. (but used a normal diode and another CMOS: GD74LS08 )

Furthermore, this circuit does not "pass" the 5-second pulses -- it shortens all pulses by its delay time.

@ClarkSuperman The 7408 isn’t CMOS (it’s TTL) and in this case the CMOS input in gate is mandatory. The standard Si diode is Ok but will discharge to 0.6V instead of 0.3V. It will corrupt the 1 sec timing a bit.

I don’t recall whether CMOS switches at Vcc/2 or bit higher (with some hysteresis), but it isn’t important, just use 33uF capacitor instead if does, all other parts stays the same.

Yeah it kind of works like a delay when i short down the input to earth but not sure how to apply it. it's a cool delay though.
